# The compiler won't find namespace 'System.Windows.Interop'

Tags: c#, winforms

Help!!**The compiler won't find namespace **'System.Windows.Interop'****

recently I built a winform project,and want to use a dll (do some d3d rendering work) generated by another c++ project;

```
OS: win7 x64
IDE: vs2013
Language:C#
current framework used in the winform project is ".net framework 4.5"
```

And in the winform project,I created a class file named MCDllOpt.cs
The code is as follow.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Interop; // Error occured here!

namespace WorldEditor
{
    class MCDllOpt
    {

    }
}
```

And here's part of what the compiler tells.

```
1>CoreCompile:
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702,2008 /nostdlib+ /platform:anycpu32bitpreferred /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE /errorendlocation /preferreduilang:en-US /highentropyva+ /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Data.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Deployment.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Drawing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\WorldEditor.exe /subsystemversion:6.00 /resource:obj\Release\WorldEditor.Form1.resources /resource:obj\Release\WorldEditor.Properties.Resources.resources /target:winexe /utf8output Form1.cs Form1.Designer.cs MCDllOpt.cs Program.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs Properties\Resources.Designer.cs Properties\Settings.Designer.cs "C:\Users\Think\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj\Release\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_E7A71F73-0F8D-4B9B-B56E-8E70B10BC5D3.cs obj\Release\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_036C0B5B-1481-4323-8D20-8F5ADCB23D92.cs obj\Release\\TemporaryGeneratedFile_5937a670-0e60-4077-877b-f7221da3dda1.cs
1>F:\WorldEditor\WorldEditor\WorldEditor\MCDllOpt.cs(6,22,6,29): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.78
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

After several minutes' searching.I found out that I need to add references specified.
But after I add all the references whose prefix is 'System.Windows',the problem's still not fixed!
[image]

Does anyone have this problem before? Please help me.

Comment: I assume that if you use C++ dll in winforms project, then you need `System.Runtime.InteropServices` namespace.

Comment: I think your namespace is wrong. Please give it the correct namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) namespace. One assembly you could reference (which contributes classes to that namespace) is `PresentationCore.dll`. But what classes from `System.Windows.Interop` do you actually need since you have that `using` directive? What you need to reference is the assemblies where those classes are.

Maybe the solution is to remove the `using`?

If you make a WinForm application, possibly you don't need any WPF namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.aspx), `System.Windows.Interop` is for WPF:

> Provides supporting types for interoperation between Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and other technologies such as Win32 APIs and provides base classes for other specific interoperation scenarios involving WPF.

Comment: I just want to use some Win32 API to get the canvas's HWND and initialize D3D11Device and D3D11DeviceContext.